# Clickable subitem in a expandablelistview (clickonlistener)

Tags: java, android, android-studio

This is the ExpandableListViewAdpater, that contain the code below

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseExpandableListAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

 public class ExpandableListViewAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

private Context context;
private List<String> parentDataSource;
private HashMap<String, List<String>> childDataSource;

public ExpandableListViewAdapter(Context context, List<String> childParent, HashMap<String, List<String>> child) {
    this.context = context;
    this.parentDataSource = childParent;
    this.childDataSource = child;
}

@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    return this.parentDataSource.size();
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    return this.childDataSource.get(this.parentDataSource.get(groupPosition)).size();
}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
    return parentDataSource.get(groupPosition);
}

@Override
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return this.childDataSource.get(parentDataSource.get(groupPosition)).get(childPosition);
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    return groupPosition;
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return childPosition;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View view = convertView;
    if(view == null){
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.parent_layout, parent, false);
    }

    String parentHeader = (String)getGroup(groupPosition);

    TextView parentItem = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.parent_layout);
    parentItem.setText(parentHeader);
    return view;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View view = convertView;
    if(view == null){
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.child_layout, parent, false);
    }

    String childName = (String)getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

    TextView childItem = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.child_layout);
    childItem.setText(childName);
    return view;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return true;
}

}
```

Now the code in the main activity, so i have created a new activity called Objetivo, and i want that when i run the app and click in Objetivo (A sub-item in the expandable listview), it open/goes to the activity Objetivo that is created.

```
package com.example.lucas.v3;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

private ExpandableListView expandableListView;
private List<String>parentHeaderInformation;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    parentHeaderInformation = new ArrayList<String>();
   //Para adicionar item no menu, que abrira sub-menus.
    parentHeaderInformation.add("Interferencia");

    HashMap<String, List<String>> allChildItems = returnGroupedChildItems();
    expandableListView = (ExpandableListView)findViewById(R.id.expandableListView);
    ExpandableListViewAdapter expandableListViewAdapter = new ExpandableListViewAdapter(getApplicationContext(), parentHeaderInformation, allChildItems);

    expandableListView.setAdapter(expandableListViewAdapter);
}
private HashMap<String, List<String>> returnGroupedChildItems(){

    HashMap<String, List<String>> childContent = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

    // para cada capitulo, adicionar o codigo abaixo
    List<String> Interferencia = new ArrayList<String>();
    Interferencia.add("Tema");
    Interferencia.add("Objetivo");
    Interferencia.add("Desenvolvimento");
    Interferencia.add("Aplicação");
    Interferencia.add ("Exercicios");
    Interferencia.add ("Referencia Bibliografica");

    // para cada capitulo adicionado, adicionar o codigo seguinte onde o   
    //primeiro é o zero.
   childContent.put(parentHeaderInformation.get(0), Interferencia);


    return childContent;
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create your own custom adapter.

Create a new class, e.g. `CustomExpandableListViewAdapter` that extends `BaseExpandableListViewAdapter`.

When implementing the methods, you'll have to override `getChildView` and you'll end up with something like this (not sure if that's **exactly** it but you'll be able to handle any minor differences).

```
@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
                        boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View view = convertView;
    convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickLister(){

        @override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (childPosition==1) {
                context.startActivity(...);
            }  
        });

    return view;
}
```

You'll have to pass the `context` through your constructor e.g.

```
CustomExpandableListViewAdapter(Context context) { 
    this.context = context;
}
```

Comment: Please Rafael Cardoso, can i u help me?

Comment: Eu acabei de ver que você é brasileiro, este é um projeto de iniciação cientifica você poderia me auxiliar em alguns pontos qnd for realmente necessario ?

Comment: @LucasJoséRodriguês Poderia sim ;) Te mandei um email. Abraços

Comment: tentei aplicar seu código e não está executando